# How to clean up command line spinner

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

I recreated an implementation of a spinner for my command line script:

```
class Spinner
  GLYPHS = %w[| / – \\ | / – \\]
  def render
    Thread.new do
      while true
        GLYPHS.each do |glyph|
          print "\r#{glyph}"
          sleep 0.10
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It is used as:

```
puts "Querying the API..."
@s = Spinner.new
@s.render
# do some stuff, return some data, output it to the command line
puts "All done."
```

and the resulting command line output is something like

```
Querying the API...[spinner is spinning here]
\RESULTS
|RESULTS
\RESULTS

|All done.
```

When the script is over, the last glyph remains. My understanding is that the `"\r"` at the beginning of the print string is meant to clean up the past glyph. I manually print a `"\r"`, which is unintuitive and makes the code look not great. I like for the spinner to not leave one of its glyphs in front of the result without manually having to print `"\r"` before each output line.

Comment: What is the purpose of defining `GLYPHS = %w[| / – \\ | / – \\]` with two cycles? What changes if it were `GLYPHS = %w[| / – \\]`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the thread.  I tweaked your Spinner class a little bit.

```
class Spinner

  GLYPHS = %w[| / – \\ | / – \\]

  def initialize(msg = nil)
    print "#{msg}... " unless msg.nil?
    @thread = Thread.new do
      while true
        GLYPHS.each do |glyph|
          print "\b#{glyph}"
          sleep 0.10
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def stop(msg = nil)
    @thread.exit
    print  "\b#{msg}\n"
  end

end
```

When running it looks like this:

```
Querying the API.../
```

And when all done like this:

```
Querying the API...All done.
```